# VB: Copy Excel Cells to Word and Keep Excel Format

Tags: vb.net, excel, format, copy, vba

I have these Excel cells formatted as comma (E.G. 9,000,000) which I copy into fixed tables in Word. I use VB Script to do so (see below). But when the value goes into Word, the comma disappears. From 9,000,000 to 9000000. How will I be able to retain the original format of that number? Thank you.

```
Sub test()

Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdApp As Word.Application


Dim tbl As Word.Table


Dim FileName As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer

Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path

ChDir Path
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & "\Excel2.xlsx"

Set TARGET_FILE = Workbooks("Excel2.xlsx")

TARGET_FILE.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
SRC_A2 = Range("A2").Value
SRC_B2 = Range("B2").Value

FileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Practice\Word.docx"
Set wdApp = New Word.Application

wdApp.Visible = True 'add this to see the Word instance and document
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName)

Set tbl = wdDoc.Tables(1)


tbl.Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.Text = SRC_A2
tbl.Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text = SRC_B2


End Sub
```

Comment: This does not appear to be VB Script (as mentioned in the question) or VB.Net (as tagged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `Text` property, instead of the `Value` property, you will get the value of the cell looking as it does in Excel:

```
SRC_A2 = Range("A2").Text
SRC_B2 = Range("B2").Text
```

It would also be a good idea to declare the type of all your variables, e.g.

```
Dim SRC_A2 As String
Dim SRC_B2 As String
```